# Find 25 nearest addresses for table with Latitude and Longitude

Tags: mysql, gis, latitude-longitude, distance

I'm trying to create a new table with a list of each address in another table and it's 10 nearest addreses. Each record has latitude and longitude. Clearly running all against all is much more work than is needed (several million records).

However it occurred to me if I resorted/indexed the table using latitude, longitude it would then sort by distance automatically and I could just step through each record doing ID+/- 25.

However this still leaves me with the question; what would the query to find the distance between two records each having latitude/longitude look like?

Comment: Why are you creating a new table with a hundred million records, instead of just querying the ten nearest for a given address when needed? Changes to the address table will result in mass recomputation of the derived table.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd have indexes on the latitude and longitude. Then I'd do something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE (table.latitude BETWEEN (query_lat - x) AND (query_lat + x)) AND (table.longitude BETWEEN (query_long - y) AND (query_long + y));`, refining `x` and `y` each time until the count got down around 100 or so records. (Maybe I'd store the final `x` and `y` values into the record for the query address so I don't have to do so many queries next time.) Then I'd run the query for all the columns, not just `COUNT(*)`, to get the actual latitude and longitude and maybe use a heap queue to get the 25 shortest distances.

The real difficult thing here is that the relationship between longitude and distance depends on latitude as well; they're not independent. I'm not sure putting a spherical coordinate transformation into the query is a great idea.

Your use-latitude/longitude-for-id trick isn't going to work because it just won't sort right. For example, that sort would tell you Houston is closer to San Antonio than Austin is.

Comment: Since the table is a building/address one the lat/long sort seemed to get my in the ballpark for each address. I'm wondering if I know the basic distance I'm looking for (say two city blocks or say 150-200 meters) this would help? In other words find closest within 150-200 meters?

Comment: The method I outlined should help by winnowing out most of the entries in the database and getting you just the ones within, say, a quarter mile. For a city, the variance of longitude over latitude shouldn't be to bad, but might lead to some odd results in cities near the poles. Sorting by latitude then longitude still won't work. For example, if you have an area with streets that are nearly aligned to the compass directions, all the locations along the east-west streets, no matter how distant, will seem "closer" than locations less than a block away north or south.

Comment: Yeah I kind of realized that when walking home tonight and thinking about it.  Which would make idenitfying 'worst case scenario' a matter of max # per block per city. One thing I can do on the addresses btw is identify/extract the street so I could use lat/long and then where Street!=Street. So then in your query is query_lat an msql distance function? And for X and Y is there some value I can use in lat and long to specify/limut by 100 yards?

Comment: `query_lat` and `query_long` are the latitude and longitude of the starting point you're interested in, i.e. the "from" address. `x` and `y` are distances from the starting point along the respective axes. So the query gets you every address in a rectangle centered on the address of interest. Again, the idea is to exclude as many locations as possible that can't possibly be close enough. While it is possible to use an equation to compute distance in the query for every record, that query will probably be really slow because of the `sqrt()` call.

Comment: If you have to do everything in SQL, you can use this as a "pre-filter" subquery, then compute distances only on that subset of locations.